# Context rerender prevention with useMemo()

Tags: reactjs

When researching contexts I've stumbled across a common pattern more than once:

```
const storeContext = React.createContext()

const Provider = (children) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState();

  const ctxValue = React.useMemo(() => [state, setState], [state]);

  return (
    <storeContext.Provider value={ctxValue}>
      {children}
    </storeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Many people seem to use `useMemo`in this case, and I'm not sure why. At first glance, it seems to make sense since passing an object/array directly would mean that this object would get recreated on every render and trigger the children to be rerendered since a new reference is passed. At second glance, I struggle with the pattern.

I'm not sure how this pattern could potentially prevent any rerenders. If a component up the tree changes, all children (including the context) rerender anyway, and if `state` changes, the provider rerenders (rightfully) itself as well as all children.

The only thing that I see `useMemo` do is to save a tiny bit of memory since we're not recreating the `ctxValue` object on every render.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something here, and would love some input.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the second part of your question.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because every render would create a new Array instance. By using useMemo, the array passed to the context is only ever changed when state changes. A better way to do this would be to just pass the result of useState to the context:

```
const storeContext = React.createContext()

const Provider = (children) => {
  const ctxValue = React.useState();

  return (
    <storeContext.Provider value={ctxValue}>
      {children}
    </storeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

---

## Update

So, I was pretty curious as to how React would handle re-renders and contexts updating. I was really surprised to find that React will only re-render a component if the props change.

For example, if you have something like this:

```js
function MyComponent(){
  const ctxValue = useContext(MyContext);
  return (<div>
    value: {ctxValue}
    <MyOtherComponent />
  </div>);
}
```

And you render that component, `MyOtherComponent` will only render once, ever, assuming the component doesn't use any hooks that can update its internal state.

The same goes for Context.Provider. The only time it will re-render is when the value updates, but its children will not re-render unless they directly depend on that context.

I create a simple sandbox to demonstrate this.

Basically, I set up a lot of different ways to nest children, and some children rely on the context, and others don't. If you click the "+" button, the context is updated and you'll see the render count only increase for those components.

```js
const Ctx = React.createContext();

function useRenderCount(){
  const count = React.useRef(0);

  count.current += 1;

  return count.current;
}

function wrapInRenderCount(name,child){
  const count = useRenderCount();
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {name} was rendered {count} times.
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginLeft: "1em" }}>{child}</div>
    </div>
  );

}

function ContextProvider(props) {
  const [count, setState] = React.useState(0);

  const increase = React.useCallback(() => {
      setState((v) => v + 1);
  }, []);

  const context = React.useMemo(() => [increase, count], [increase, count]);

  return wrapInRenderCount('ContextProvider',
    <Ctx.Provider value={context}>
      {props.children}
    </Ctx.Provider>
  );
}

function ContextUser(props){
  const [increase, count] = React.useContext(Ctx);

  return wrapInRenderCount('ContextUser',
    <div>
      <div>
        Count: {count}
        <button onClick={increase}>
          ++
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function RandomWrapper(props){
  return wrapInRenderCount('RandomWrapper',<div>
    <div>
      Wrapped
    </div>
    <div style={{marginLeft:'1em'}}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  </div>);
}

function RandomContextUserWrapper(props){
  return wrapInRenderCount('RandomContextUserWrapper',
    <div>
      <ContextUser></ContextUser>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return wrapInRenderCount('App',
    <RandomWrapper>
      <ContextProvider>
          <RandomWrapper>
            <ContextUser>
              <RandomWrapper>
                <RandomContextUserWrapper>
                  <RandomWrapper>
                    <ContextUser/>
                    </RandomWrapper>
                </RandomContextUserWrapper>
              </RandomWrapper>
            </ContextUser>
            <RandomWrapper>
                <RandomContextUserWrapper />
              </RandomWrapper>
          </RandomWrapper>
      </ContextProvider>
    </RandomWrapper>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```